# How do I build with GitHub actions through Expo CLI

Tags: expo, github-actions

Is there a way to build an expo build through GitHub Actions instead of Expo Turtle? I don't have a Mac so I have to use virtual building. I know that it takes longer to build on Turtle than on Actions.

If it is possible how would I do it?

Where I originally saw this for another framework: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-remote-builds/blob/master/docs/CIRCLECI.md

Edit: Haven't tested yet but this looks promising; https://dev.to/justussoh/using-github-actions-to-seamlessly-deploy-expo-applications-part-1-3jfb

Comment: Yeah looks like you have found the answer, follow the tut, then look into the actual action which is used: https://github.com/expo/expo-github-action

Answer (score 1):

You can build standalone apps with expo on GH Actions. It's still turtle-cli build, but run on macos-latest runner;

You have to remember that your exported sources should be uploaded to some public server previously for further OTA updates.

Here you can find a simple workflow, how to do this with GH Actions with example on GH repository: https://www.daily-coding.net/posts/building-standalone-expo-apps-with-github-actions. In README you can also find an explanation, which credentials and secrets are needed.